# How to deploy from docker hub to openshift?

Tags: docker, openshift, dockerhub

I'm trying to deploy a docker image from docker hub on openshift.

I crated an image with a simple spring boot rest application:
https://hub.docker.com/r/ernst1970/my-rest

After logging into openshift an choosing the correct project I do

```
oc new-app ernst1970/my-rest
```

And I get

```
W0509 13:17:28.781435   16244 dockerimagelookup.go:220] Docker registry lookup failed: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Clien
t.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)                                                                                                                                                 
error: Errors occurred while determining argument types:                                                                                                                                   

ernst1970/my-rest as a local directory pointing to a Git repository:  GetFileAttributesEx ernst1970/my-rest: The system cannot find the path specified.                                    

Errors occurred during resource creation:                                                                                                                                                  
error: no match for "ernst1970/my-rest"                                                                                                                                                    

The 'oc new-app' command will match arguments to the following types:                                                                                                                      

  1. Images tagged into image streams in the current project or the 'openshift' project                                                                                                    
     - if you don't specify a tag, we'll add ':latest'                                                                                                                                     
  2. Images in the Docker Hub, on remote registries, or on the local Docker engine                                                                                                         
  3. Templates in the current project or the 'openshift' project                                                                                                                           
  4. Git repository URLs or local paths that point to Git repositories                                                                                                                     

--allow-missing-images can be used to point to an image that does not exist yet.                                                                                                           

See 'oc new-app -h' for examples.
```

I also tried with

```
oc new-app mariadb
```

But got the same error message.

I thought this might be a proxy problem. So I added the proxy to my `.profile`:

```
export http_proxy=http://ue73011:secret@dev-proxy.wzu.io:3128
export https_proxy=http://ue73011:secret@dev-proxy.wzu.io:3128
```

Unfortunately this did not change anything.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

your docker daemon needs the proxy so it can reach the DockerHub. You can specify proxy server by providing it as an environment variable for the docker daemon.

Take a look at the official Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

Add a file */etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf* which should contain following

```
[Service]    
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.example.com,.corp"
```

Reload your changes and restart docker daemon

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Verify by doing a simple "docker pull ... "

Comment: If I get you right, I would have to do this on the openshift server? Unfortunately I don't have any access to this machine other than the openshift Web UI or the openshift client.

Comment: Unfortunately, "oc new-app" does not (IMHO) accept any proxy settings. The proxy settings need to be set on the environment in which the "new-app" is actually running on. Maybe you could push your image to some registry that is available to your OpenShift (i.e. internal registry).